# Store cross site collection data

Tags: site-collection, web-application, data

Is there a way to store data (strings, maybe xml) in SharePoint that can be accessible to all the site collections in a web application?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint Server (Standard)

Comment: What version? 2007? 2010? 2013?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [PropertyBag](http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2009/10/27/using-sharepoint-built-in-property-bags-spwebapplication.properties-and-spweb.properties.aspx) associated with the WebApplication object.

Comment: This is the place where to store small data. If you need a lot of data, some kind of tables, you may have to end up with creating a list somewhere, queriable from any other place.